# Is there such a thing as a SAS switch?

Tags: hard-drive, switch, sas

I know infiniband uses largely the same cables as the SAS connected hard drive bays (JBODs), and infiniband has switches for its own purposes. I know also that SAS connected units have the capacity for daisy chaining to allow up  to 1024 hard drives to be connected to a single controller port.

1. Does something like a switch exist that effectively multiplexes a controller port out to a large number of SAS connected external enclosures?
2. Is there a common name for such a device?
3. Is there a technological reason why such a device could not exist?

Comment: You're looking for a device like a SAS expander. SAS and Infiniband are pretty different so it's not accurate to claim they're doing the same thing.

Comment: SAS expander sounds like the right type of unit, but from what I've seen they are implemented as daisy chain units in hard drive enclosure themselves. I'm wondering if there's a dedicated unit that multiplexes and is the central connection point of many enclosures. It would look a look a lot like a switch with an uplink and seems like it might have a similar behaviour.

Comment: @Mokubai I don't see how this is a shopping recommendation that will become obsolete quickly. If such a device exists then is will exist forever; if it doesn't then there may be a good technological reason why.

Comment: If you make it about specific cards etc. it would become obsolete quickly as the line up of vendors frequently changes. Mentioning that [SAS Extenders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_Attached_SCSI#SAS_expanders) exist works, mentioning the specific model of vendor X and asking which to buy doesn't. You can buy them as PCI-E cards. You would either use backplanes with a suitable connector or you would use a fan out/sideband cable depending on what you actually want to do.

Answer (score 0):

SAS Switch

The LSI 6160 (Broadcom) SAS Switch is an example:

https://docs.broadcom.com/doc/12353463

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Am I right in saying that a switch in this case amounts to a 'tree' of expanders, n levels deep?